# Pymongo iterate through list of docs

Tags: python, arrays, mongodb, iteration, pymongo

I'm a complete newbie to Stackoverflow, MongoDB, and PyMongo.  I have a database with a collection called posts that looks like the following.

```
{
    EXPERIMENT:1,
    DATA[
        {TIMESTAMP:1/1/1000 00:00:00,
         "A":1,
         "B":2,
         "C":3
        },
        {TIMESTAMP:1/1/1000 00:00:01,
         "A":4,
         "B":5,
         "C":6
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm not even sure if this is the best way to model the data structure but it's what I have right now and I would like to query it.  When I try the query,

```
db.posts.find({EXPERIMENT:1},{DATA.TIMESTAMP:1, _id:0})
```

I get what I want, however, I get "DATA" back which I think is a list of documents but I can't iterate through it.

```
for result in db.posts.find({EXPERIMENT:1},{DATA.TIMESTAMP:1, _id:0}):
    print result;
```

This just prints one massive thing rather than going through DATA line by line.  I tried also:

```
for result in db.posts.find({EXPERIMENT:1},{DATA.TIMESTAMP:1, _id:0}):
    for value in result:
        print value;
```

I then get the result DATA, again, not something that I can iterate through.  Clearly, I'm missing something fundamental.  Can someone please point me in the right direction?  Maybe a little off topic but do you also have book suggestions that might cover this?

Thank you!

EDIT:
Ultimately, I would like a result set that looks like:

```
DATA = [1/1/1000 00:00:00, 1/1/1000 00:00:01]
```

where DATA is a traditional python list so that I can do:

```
for value in DATA:
    print value;
    # Do something else with data
```

Again, I know I'm missing something really basic.  Thanks for your help and understanding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It prints one "big thing" like this?

```
In [12]: for result in db.test.find({'EXPERIMENT':1}, {'DATA.TIMESTAMP':1, '_id':0}): print result
{u'DATA': [{u'TIMESTAMP': u'1/1/1000 00:00:00'}, {u'TIMESTAMP': u'1/1/1000 00:00:01'}]}
```

Then, you should try pprint:

```
In [13]: from pprint import pprint

In [14]: for result in db.test.find({'EXPERIMENT':1}, {'DATA.TIMESTAMP':1, '_id':0}): pprint(result)
{u'DATA': [{u'TIMESTAMP': u'1/1/1000 00:00:00'},
           {u'TIMESTAMP': u'1/1/1000 00:00:01'}]}
```

You can also do:

```
In [15]: for result in db.test.find({'EXPERIMENT':1}, {'DATA.TIMESTAMP':1, '_id':0}):
   ....:     for k, v in result.items():
   ....:         print k, v
   ....:         
DATA [{u'TIMESTAMP': u'1/1/1000 00:00:00'}, {u'TIMESTAMP': u'1/1/1000 00:00:01'}]
```

Comment: Hi @Oz124, thank you for your quick response!  Sorry, I feel like I haven't asked the question properly (I'll edit question).  This still gives me all the data (timestamp key : timestamp value) in a list that I can't seem to iterate through.  In postgres and psycopg, if I iterate through a cursor, I get the values which I can then process.

Comment: Pymongo does not return "value" it returns a generator of dictionaries. Each dictionary can be iterated with the pattern I showed you.

Comment: Dictionary!  That was the word I was looking for and you were absolutely correct.  Thank you.